# How does this print function moves pointer to next item in the linked list?

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion

```
struct ll {
    int num;
    struct ll *next;
};

struct ll *head;

main() {
    /* code to assign head pointer some memory */

    print(head->next);
}
```

I read that the `print()` function in above code moves the poiner to next item. How does this move the head pointer to next item?

Answer (score 2):

`print()` must look something like:

```
print(struct ll *foo) {
  // code
  head = head->next;
  // other code
}
```

Note that this is not good code in a variety of ways, but that's how it would move `head` to point to the next item.

Comment: head is undefined in your code? Perhaps you meant foo->head = foo->head->next;

Comment: @Daniel Actually, he probably meant `foo = foo->next;`.

Comment: @Daniel: `head` is defined as a global variable in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `head` pointer is a global and you don't want to alter it while simply traversing the list. This will walk through the list and print each `num` field.

```
void print(struct ll *node) {
    while (node) {
        printf("%d\n", node->num);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

main() {
    /* code to assign head pointer some memory */
    print(head);
}
```